# Is is possible to use Profiling API right from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, profiling, clr-profiling-api

I just want to use .NET Profiling API (`ICorProfilerCallback` etc) but at the same time don't want to deal with C++. I've been looking around for a while and haven't found any example in C# but C# + C++ where the most interesting part is written using C++.

Comment: You want to find bottlenecks, or memory leaks? If the former, you should be aware of [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). It's effective and doesn't need an API, only a debugger.

Comment: what problem do you have with C++? what is your scenario?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, you cannot implement the CLR profiling APIs in managed code (C# or otherwise) since the profiling callbacks are called at very specific times when the managed environment is assumed to be in a certain state.  Implementing your callbacks in managed code would violate a lot of assumptions.

David Broman, the developer of the CLR profiling APIs, has [this to say](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxtoolsdev/thread/c7d81f63-69c7-4f3c-a34c-8d627a83f787/):

> You need to write your profiler in
>   C++.  The profiler is called by the
>   runtime at very delicate points during
>   execution of the profiled application,
>   and it is often extremely unsafe to be
>   running managed code at those points.

[David's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032303/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr) is a great resource for dealing with the CLR profiling APIs.

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.html

Comment: @KarelFrajták, are you saying that Pex counts as unmanaged code and can access the COM APIs, or is this link completely unrelated to this question?

Comment: I think there was an information on implementing the profiler methods in C# (it is not there anymore). But see http://www.jasonbock.net/News/Item/741d5181-6a06-4e7f-8a00-e03660dd16cf - quoting: "Pex is also interesting because of the technologies and frameworks that it uses that do all sorts of advanced, cool stuff. One, in particular, is called ExtendedReflection. This is basically a managed profiler - yes, you read that right. For the longest time, I was under the impression that you can't write a profiler in .NET in managed code, but I was wrong because ExtendedReflection does just that."