# Is there any debugger library which can attach to process? (C#)

Tags: c#, debugging, pydbg

I'm looking for some external library which will allow me to attach to some other running process.
I actually want to detect all the API Functions that the process is using.
I can do it through **Python** (with the module **PyDbg**), but **I want to do this task in C#**.
Is there any library that can do this work? I will be glad to hear about some libraries which can do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need a profiler, not a debugger.

Comment: @leppie Thank you for your reply. Do you know some library that I can achieve my goal with it?

Comment: The CLR Profiler API can do this, but it is C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is is possible to use Profiling API right from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736845/is-is-possible-to-use-profiling-api-right-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

No. You should be looking to use a lower level language to do this.